# Best way to Test an API Web Service using Automation

Tags: rest, api, web-services, automated-tests

I am looking for the best way to test this scenario using automation. Before you mention or ask, yes, i have throughly searched to make sure or even get info or knowledge on this topic.

I have a web service that provides various pricing for health insurance. The pricing is based on different class category of race, age, location etc. All that is inputed into the web service to get the fee for the client.

Right now everything is done locally with SoupUI. As you know SoupUI does not have a way for you to randomly change the data in the body, but i need a way to automate this so random age, race, location, etc can be inputed in and verify the result against a CSV file with the information.

Is this possible or is there a better way to test this web service?

-
Per @lloyd request, because he is King here and other known methods i know:

UI Option: We build a UI to interface with the API and use Selenium to run the countless scenarios we have, but they do not want to do this. They are more incline on testing the API itself.

Ruby: Use Ruby to connect to the API, using Rspec and Airborne (https://github.com/brooklynDev/airborne), the downsize of this is also the same as using SoupUI. Everything is entered in manually, and the code just runs through the various variations we have to get the return and match it against what it should be.

I also found another tool, https://assertible.com/ but the downsize of that is we cannot limit the random generator between 2 selected numbers, plus no way to do the comparison.

Then there is Postman, which is also similar to SoupUI so not a real automation since we cannot change the values in the body. http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/09/03/how-to-write-powerful-automated-api-tests-with-postman-newman-and-jenkins/

Comment: [How to write automated tests for APIs using Postman – Part 1](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/03/07/writing-automated-tests-for-apis-using-postman/). [http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Comment: @lloyd Did you even read? I clearly said that in the first paragraph, and i even mentioned Postman and how it is not true automation.

Comment: I cannot see any research. Please list some of your research and provide a [http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/).

Comment: Done, any further request, since i am only asking a community of the best way to go about it. :/